# Select Data from 2 tables

Tags: php

I am making post like page in android studio. There are two tables firs name is Image another is Image_like. Image have datas for user information and post information.Image_like have image_id , username and liked. liked is just 1 because ı will contol this in andorid studio that user like this image or not. So ı want to select datas from Image and Image_like.This is my php codes :

```
<?php

    $DB_USER='id2766';        
    $DB_PASS='05455028';        
    $DB_HOST='localhost';     
    $DB_NAME='id27666';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $sql="SELECT id, username, image, caption , profilpicture, likenumber , date FROM Images ORDER BY date DESC";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);

    while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $output[]=$e; 
            }

    print(json_encode($output)); 
    $mysqli->close();
  ?>
```

And ı am using this php code but its not working :

```
SELECT * FROM Image UNION ALL SELECT liked FROM image_like WHERE Image.id = image_like.id AND Image.username = image_like.username
```

Comment: I don't say this often, but I suggest you get back to learning PHP and SQL a bit before you continue with what you're trying to accomplish. If you don't, you will have to come back here with more questions than you will receive responses to, and it'll be very frustrating for you (and annoying for the community). The fact that you call a SQL query "php code" shows that you could to work through a few tutorials in both. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the data from tables this query should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Image 
    JOIN image_like ON Image.id = image_like.id
WHERE Image.username = image_like.username
```

Comment: Sir give me error : SQL query: Documentation


SELECT * 
FROM Image 
    JOIN image_like ON Image.id = image_like.id
WHERE Image.username = image_like.username LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1109 - Unknown table 'Image' in information_schema

Comment: sir and ı want to liked number from image_like

Comment: It says that it doesn't exists a table called Image. Maybe it's Images ?

Answer (score -1):

You can LEFT JOIN the two tables to get their rows

Comment: You should include an example